# Can't perform a React state update with Formik on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am getting the following warning when I click the button to submit the form:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
Formik@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3815:28
div
div
CheckIn@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:382:17
Route@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:43553:29
```

The warning occurs when the form is valid. Once I click the button a second time, it successfully submits.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CheckIn({ user, setUser }) {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            name: "",
            mail: ""
          }}
          validate={(values) => {
            const errors = {};

            if (!values.mail && user.mail) {
              values.mail = user.mail;
            }

            if (!values.name && user.name) {
              values.name = user.name;
            }

            if (!values.mail) {
              errors.mail = "Required";
            } else if (
              !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.mail)
            ) {
              errors.mail = "Invalid mail address";
            }

            return errors;
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            history.push("/success");
            setUser(values);
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            isSubmitting,
          }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="name"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                style={errors.name ? { border: "2px solid red" } : {}}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.name || user.name}
              />
              <input
                type="email"
                name="mail"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
                style={errors.mail ? { border: "2px solid red" } : {}}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.mail || user.mail}
              />

              <button
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                className="btn wide"
              >
                Checkin
              </button>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, the warning doesn't help me, as I don't understand it on the one side, and on the other side, there is no useEffect.

Comment: The error is due to calling `history.push` which navigates away from the page and causes the form to unmount and calling `setSubmitting` after that.  I don't get the error anymore if I move the `history.push` to be the last thing in `onSubmit`, but I don't love this as a solution because state updates are asynchronous, so it's still possible for the state to be updated after unmount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem: `history.push`

This error is caused by the `onSubmit` handler of your form:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
  history.push("/success");
  setUser(values);
  setSubmitting(false);
}}
```

The first thing that you do is call `history.push` which navigates away from the page and causes the `Formik` component to unmount.  You then call `setSubmitting` which attempts to update the state of the `Formik` component - but it has already unmounted so you get the error *"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."*

Just moving the `history.push` to be the last of the actions in the list caused the error to go away for me, but I don't love this solution because React `setState` calls are asynchronous so it is still technically possible for the error to occur.  I don't see why you would need to manually call `setSubmitting` when you are leaving this page, so my recommendation is to remove that call entirely.

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
  setUser(values);
  history.push("/success");
}}
```

Make sure that `setUser` is not updating the state of component which will be unmounted by the navigation.

Comment: This is a perfect answer! Thank you very much and for sure: This is working!

Comment: I removed the setSubmitting line and that cleared up this issue.  Thanks!